# Need to copy a particular Git commit from another repository

Tags: git, commit

I am new to git

I need to get this commit https://github.com/DJNoXD/candied-kernel/commit/3a9f10b82d9a5b6dc54ceab4d7edb60c5a7f19e6

to my git https://github.com/nayak94/nayak-kernel/commits/0.1

I have no clue what to do, any help would be greatful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
git remote add candied-kernel git@github.com:DJNoXD/candied-kernel.git
git fetch candied-kernel master
git cherry-pick 3a9f10b
```

If it's a one-off thing, you might want to download the patch file instead by appending `.patch` to the URL (i.e. https://github.com/DJNoXD/candied-kernel/commit/3a9f10b82d9a5b6dc54ceab4d7edb60c5a7f19e6.patch) and then use

```
git am /path/to/3a9f10b82d9a5b6dc54ceab4d7edb60c5a7f19e6.patch
```

Comment: WOw, that did the trick i was stuck in the third line , thanks a lot :D